# A proof I don't understand in analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am reading a book in analysis it is proving the Ratio test, but their is some step I don't understand or I am not entirely sure of how they got that result.

(Ratio Test) Let $\sum a_n$ be a series of nonzero terms

1. If $\lim \sup|a_{n + 1}/a_n| < 1$ , then the series converges absolutely.
2. if $\lim \inf|a_{n+1}/a_n| > 1$ , then series diverges.

Proof: 
Let $\lim \sup |a_{n + 1}/ a_n| = L$. If $L < 1$ , then choose $r$ so that $L < r < 1$. By theorem Let $Sn$ be a bounded sequence and $m = \lim \sup s_n$. then the following properties hold

a) For every $E > 0$ there exists $N, E$ natural numbers such that $n \geq N$ then $sn < m + E$ so by this theorem N E natural numbers such that $n \geq N$ then $|a_{n + 1} / a_n| \leq r$. that is $|a_{n + 1} \leq r|a_n|$ it follows easily by induction that $|a_{N + k}| \leq r^k|a_N|$.

Now there is two things I am not sure about first one I think I know why but I would like someone to tell me if my reasoning is correct or not the second one I don't see it.  So they say $n \geq N$ implies that  $|a_{n + 1}|$ how they got this is by the fact that since $r$ is the sup so we will have $|a_{n + 1} / a_n| < M + \varepsilon$ which implies that
$|a_{n + 1} / a_n| < r$ since $r$ here is lim sup and since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary we can just remove it right is my reasoning correct? My second question I don't understand the induction how did they get that ? If someone could explain that would be great.

Comment: Without LaTeX to write properly mathematics it is going to be pretty tough to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know $\big(\sup\{a_k | k \geq n \} \big)$ is a decreasing sequence and $\big(\inf\{a_k | k \geq n \} \big)$ is an increasing sequence with respect to $n$.

Note $\limsup(a_n)<c$, then $\sup\{a_k | k\geq n\} $ eventually less than $c$, hence $a_n$ eventually less than c.

Similarly, if $\liminf(a_n)>c$, then $\inf\{a_k | k\geq n\} $ eventually larger than $c$, hence $a_n$ eventually larger than c.

Then the results follow by comparison test with geometric series.